# Django: Filter objects by integer between two values

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling with a Django filtering problem I couldn't solve so far. I have a database with from/to integers, and I need a Django Filter that returns any objects where a given integer is within that range.

I have the following model (simplified):

```
class Dataset(models.Model):
    i_begin_int = models.BigIntegerField()
    i_end_int = models.BigIntegerField()
```

So for example, I have the following data:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | i_begin_int | i_end_int |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |         100 |       200 |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  2 |         150 |       300 |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  3 |        7000 |      7500 |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

So now I have an integer, lets say, 170. I need all objects where 170 is between `i_begin_int` and `i_end_int`. In the example table, that would be objects with id 1 and 2.

Is there a Django filter that I could use for this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this;

```
x = 170
Dataset.objects.filter(i_end_int__gte=x,i_begin_int__lte=x)
```

where;
gte = greater than equal to
lte = less than equal to

Comment: changing the terms around would not make any difference. It still does not work

Comment: or have a look at @garnertb's answer

Comment: yeah i got it, sorry.

Comment: Why not to use `__range`?

Comment: Is there a benefit to not using range when dealing with integer, floats?

Answer (score 3):

```
Dataset.objects.filter(i_begin_int__lte=170, i_end_int__gte=170)
```

Filter where i_begin_int is less than 170 AND the i_end_int value is greater than 170.

SQL equivalent: `SELECT * FROM appname_dataset WHERE i_begin_int <= 170 AND i_end_int >= 170`

Comment: Ah, so easy. I did try this at first, though. But I've used __gte for the begin part, which didn't work and I didn't notice. Thanks guys!!!