# how to use filter() function to fetch data between a range?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have write down a model like this:

**model.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class  SequenceDetails(models.Model):

    IDs = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.IDs
```

To fetch data from the data base i have write down a query like this:

```
SequenceDetails.objects.all().filter(country='india').filter(year='2002')
```

which is returning expected results but further I want to filter out data on the basis of country and  year range.  I have write down a query set like this.

```
SequenceDetails.objects.all().filter(country='india').filter(year__range =['2002','2005'])
```

but its now working and throwing error like given bellow:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can i achieve this thanks

Comment: You might need to provide the arguments to year__range as integers given its an integer field.

Comment: That code wouldn't give a syntax error. Please show the full error and traceback.

Comment: Here desicion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104897/django-filter-objects-by-integer-between-two-values

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution

```
SequenceDetails.objects.filter(country='india', year__lte=2005, year__gte=2002])
```

refer [gte/lte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/) django doc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here the answer

```
SequenceDetails.objects.all().filter(country='india',year__in=[2002,2000])
```

Year is the integer field so you need use **in keyword**

Comment: It's was a typo it's actually 2005 instead 200. Updated in main body

Comment: [`__range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#range) and [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in) are two different lookups, they are not interchangeable.