# Filter query between two values

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on django but can't figure how to write a query , I'm trying to get value between range of values store

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | value up    | value down|
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |         100 |       200 |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  2 |         150 |       300 |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  3 |        7000 |      7500 |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

How suppose I have value 290 , how do I get Id from range  of 150 to 300

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104897/django-filter-objects-by-integer-between-two-values/33104929 . Answer available already in the link

Comment: @Darknight that doesn't work , I need single value, instead of all

Comment: Use **`.values()`** method

Comment: `YourModel.objects.filter(valueup__gte=150, valueup__lte=300)`

Comment: @ShubhamDevgan Try this.  Model.objects.filter(valueup__lte=290, valuedown__gte=290)