# Django rest framework : how can I filter queryset in range?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I need filtering data from get request in range:

Here is my code:

model.py

```
class MainModel(TimeStampedModel):
    model_name = models.CharField(_("model_name"), max_length=240)        
    model_price = models.DecimalField(_("model_price"), max_digits=8)

class ModelAdditionalData_1(TimeStampedModel):
    model_id = models.OneToOneField(
        Model,
        verbose_name=_('related model'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='model_water_flow_data1',
        related_query_name='model_water_flow_data1'
    )
    model_param_1 = models.models.DecimalField(_("model_param_1"), max_digits=8)

class ModelAdditionalData_2(TimeStampedModel):
    model_id = models.OneToOneField(
        Model,
        verbose_name=_('related model'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='model_water_flow_data2',
        related_query_name='model_water_flow_data2'
    )
    model_param_2 = models.models.DecimalField(_("model_param_2"), max_digits=8)
```

view.py :

```
class ModelsViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet, GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ModelsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
    model_param_1 = self.request.query_params.get('model_param_1')
    model_param_2 = self.request.query_params.get('model_param_2')

    filters = {}
    if model_param_1:
        filters['model_water_flow_data1__model_param_1'] = model_param_1
    if model_param_2:
        filters['model_water_flow_data2__model_param_2'] = model_param_2

    if filters:
        return MainModel.objects.filter(**filters)

    return MainModel.objects.all()
```

How i can apply my filters for filtering data in range? For example, i wont filtering data by model_param_1 betwen 1 and 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Filter objects by integer between two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104897/django-filter-objects-by-integer-between-two-values)

Comment: @BrianD How i can use gte and lte or __range with **filters in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filters can be built like this to cover a range:

```
filters = {}

if model_param_1:
    filters['model_water_flow_data1__model_param_1__gte'] = 1
    filters['model_water_flow_data1__model_param_1__lte'] = 10

if model_param_2:
    filters['model_water_flow_data1__model_param_2__gte'] = 1
    filters['model_water_flow_data1__model_param_2__lte'] = 10

MainModel.objects.filter(**filters)
```